# What is the difference between isRunning() and isActive() in DataLine?

Tags: java, audio

What is the difference between `isRunning()` and `isActibe()` in [`DataLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html)? Both flags appear to be set when line is actually works with data.

**UPDATE**

There are 2 pairs of methods there:

1) open/close

2) start/stop

And three flags

1) isOpen

2) isRunning

3) isActive

Can anybody infer some relationships between them and/or each other? For example, it is obviously, that isRunning implies isOpen and that isActive implies isOpen, but does isActive implies isRunning or vice versa? Or they are independent?

I guess Line becomes `isOpen` immediately after `open()` called. So `isOpen` is for checking for have `open()` called or not.

Can I check somehow have I called `start()` or not? Maybe some of `isActive` or `isRunning` is for that? But which one?

**UPDATE 1**

The following code is intended to play audio from the default system sound input on to the default system sound output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {

    AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(16000f, 16, 1, true, false);

    final SourceDataLine outputLine;
    final TargetDataLine inputLine;


    outputLine = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(audioFormat);
    inputLine = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(audioFormat);

    Thread player = new Thread("player") {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int readen;

            log.info("Starting transfer");

            while( !inputLine.isOpen() ) {
                try {
                    log.info("TargetDataLine is closed, waiting");
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    interrupt();
                }
            }

            while( !inputLine.isRunning() ) {
                try {
                    log.info("TargetDataLine is not running, waiting");
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    interrupt();
                }
            }

            while((readen = inputLine.read(b,0,b.length))>=0 && !isInterrupted()) {
                outputLine.write(b,0,readen);
            }

        }
    };
    player.start();

    outputLine.open();
    outputLine.start();

    inputLine.open();
    inputLine.start();

    player.join();

}
```

Output of the code follows:

```
15:20:01.369 [player] INFO  tests.DataLineFlags01 - Starting transfer
15:20:01.371 [player] INFO  tests.DataLineFlags01 - TargetDataLine is closed, waiting
15:20:02.371 [player] INFO  tests.DataLineFlags01 - TargetDataLine is not running, waiting
15:20:02.471 [player] INFO  tests.DataLineFlags01 - TargetDataLine is not running, waiting
15:20:02.571 [player] INFO  tests.DataLineFlags01 - TargetDataLine is not running, waiting
15:20:02.671 [player] INFO  tests.DataLineFlags01 - TargetDataLine is not running, waiting
15:20:02.771 [player] INFO  tests.DataLineFlags01 - TargetDataLine is not running, waiting
...
```

this proves that TargetDataLine does not go into "running" state after `start()` was called.

The same occurs with `isActive()` flag.

This means that

(1) it is not possible to know whether `start()` was called
(2) `isRunning()` and `isActive()` flags are useless

It this right? May be they are usefull with `SourceDataLine` objects?

**UPDATE 2**

The following application

```
package testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class App 
{

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

private final AudioFormat audioFormat;
private final TargetDataLine targetDataLine;

private final Thread observer = new Thread("observer") {

    {
        setDaemon(true);
    }

    public void run() {

        while( !isInterrupted() ) {
            if( targetDataLine != null ) {
                log.info("targetDataLine: Opened={}, Active={}, Running={}", targetDataLine.isOpen(), targetDataLine.isActive(), targetDataLine.isRunning());
            }
            else {
                log.info("targetDataLine: is null");
            }
            try {
                sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

    };
};

public App() throws LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[160*2]; // 1/100 of second 

    log.info("App starting");

    log.info("Observer starting");
    observer.start();

    log.info("Sleeping 500");
    Thread.sleep(500);

    log.info("Creating targetDataLine");
    audioFormat = new AudioFormat(16000, 16, 1, true, false);
    targetDataLine = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(audioFormat);

    log.info("Sleeping 500");
    Thread.sleep(500);

    log.info("Opening targetDataLine");
    targetDataLine.open();

    log.info("Sleeping 500");
    Thread.sleep(500);

    log.info("Starting targetDataLine");
    targetDataLine.start();

    log.info("Sleeping 500");
    Thread.sleep(500);

    log.info("Reading target data line for 5 seconds");
    for(int i=0; i<50; ++i) {

        targetDataLine.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        log.info("Stage " + i);
    }

    log.info("Stopping targetDataLine");
    targetDataLine.stop();

    log.info("Sleeping 500");
    Thread.sleep(500);

    log.info("Closing targetDataLine");
    targetDataLine.close();

    log.info("Sleeping 500");
    Thread.sleep(500);

    //log.info("Interrupting observer");
    //observer.interrupt();

}



public static void main( String[] args ) throws LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException
{
    new App();
}
}
```

produces the following output:

```
20:58:23,360 0    [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - App starting
20:58:23,362 2    [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Observer starting
20:58:23,362 2    [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Sleeping 500
20:58:23,362 2    [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: is null
20:58:23,372 12   [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: is null
...
20:58:23,842 482  [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: is null
20:58:23,852 492  [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: is null
20:58:23,862 502  [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Creating targetDataLine
20:58:23,862 502  [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: is null
20:58:23,872 512  [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: is null
...
20:58:23,912 552  [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: is null
20:58:23,922 562  [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: is null
20:58:23,929 569  [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Sleeping 500
20:58:23,933 573  [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:23,943 583  [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
...
20:58:24,413 1053 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:24,423 1063 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:24,430 1070 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Opening targetDataLine
20:58:24,433 1073 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:24,443 1083 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
...
20:58:24,483 1123 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:24,493 1133 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:24,501 1141 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Sleeping 500
20:58:24,503 1143 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:24,513 1153 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=false, Running=false
...
20:58:24,983 1623 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:24,993 1633 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:25,002 1642 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Starting targetDataLine
20:58:25,002 1642 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Sleeping 500
20:58:25,003 1643 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:25,013 1653 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=false, Running=false
...
20:58:25,483 2123 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:25,493 2133 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:25,502 2142 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Reading target data line for 5 seconds
20:58:25,502 2142 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Stage 0
20:58:25,502 2142 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Stage 1
20:58:25,503 2143 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Stage 2
20:58:25,503 2143 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=true, Running=true
20:58:25,503 2143 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Stage 3
20:58:25,503 2143 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Stage 4
...
20:58:25,512 2152 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Stage 48
20:58:25,512 2152 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Stage 49
20:58:25,512 2152 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Stopping targetDataLine
20:58:25,513 2153 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=true, Running=true
20:58:25,521 2161 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Sleeping 500
20:58:25,523 2163 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:25,533 2173 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=false, Running=false
...
20:58:26,003 2643 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:26,013 2653 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=true, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:26,021 2661 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Closing targetDataLine
20:58:26,023 2663 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:26,026 2666 [main] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - Sleeping 500
20:58:26,033 2673 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:26,043 2683 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
...
20:58:26,513 3153 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
20:58:26,523 3163 [observer] INFO  testing.Test_TargetDataLine_01.App  - targetDataLine: Opened=false, Active=false, Running=false
```

Which shows that two flags are indistinguisheable.

Comment: It looks like `isRunning()` is along the lines of "is this line open" and `isActive()` is "are bits being sent through this line"

Comment: `isOpen` serves as "is this line open", not `isRunning`.

Comment: Looking at isRunning() again, "An open line begins running when the first data is presented in response to an invocation of the start method, and continues until presentation ceases in response to a call to stop or because playback completes.", It seems that once the first byte has been passed through an open line, it is running. Then, I suppose, if the line stops being active, it will still be running.

Comment: isRunning() tells you if you have called start().

Comment: But if I called `start()` but no bytes passed yet, then `isRunning()` will be `false`, So `isRunning()` does not mark I called `start()`.

Comment: I quote: `An open line begins running when the first data is presented in response to an invocation of the start method`. As I understand it, the start method will begin the flow of data. Also, if you look under `start()` see also, it references: stop(), isRunning(), LineEvent. You can use LineEvent to capture start events and store them in a HashMap<DataLine, Boolean>

Comment: Read my updated answer. It shows it (but I use a HashSet and the state is determined by the line's presence in the set).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the API docs, it says:

`isRunning()`:
Indicates whether the line is running. The default is false. An open line begins running when the first data is presented in response to an invocation of the start method, and continues until presentation ceases in response to a call to stop or because playback completes.

`isActive()`:
Indicates whether the line is engaging in active I/O (such as playback or capture). When an inactive line becomes active, it sends a START event to its listeners. Similarly, when an active line becomes inactive, it sends a STOP event.

Looking at the `start()` method, we see that `start()` allows the line to become inactive, so we might say that `isRunning()` tells us if the line can become active, and `isActive()` tells us if the line is in use (i.e. data is being transferred in the form of playback or recording)

So, in a nutshell,

`isRunning()` - Do we need to call `start()` before we use this line?

`isActive()` - Is this line in use right now?

If you must know when start() is called, use this:

```
final HashSet<Line> openLines = new HashSet<Line>();
...
DataLine myLine = getDataLine();
myLine.addListener(new LineListener(){
    public void update(LineEvent evt)
    {
        if(evt.getType().equals(LineEvent.Type.START)) openLines.add(evt.getLine());
        else if(evt.getType().equals(LineEvent.Type.STOP)) openLines.remove(evt.getLine());
    }
});

...
public boolean isLineStarted(DataLine l)
{
    return openLines.contains(l);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. From my POV a programmer calls `start()` method which asynchronously triggers some data transfer which will cause both `isRunning()` and `isActive()` flags set when actually begin. When data transfer stop then both flags will be down. I.e. no difference.

Comment: @SuzanCioc I have not personally worked with this class before, but I believe the two values could be different if Data I/O transfer is delayed after `start()`, or if Data I/O is paused during transfer. For example, suppose you are sending data to a playback device, but you pause playback. You would want to leave the line open so you can still work with it, so the line would be running but not active.

Comment: Sorry was away. No I still can't deduce relationship between all methods. I am implementing my own DataLine-s and trying to implement correct behavior.

Comment: Perhaps you should look through the source code yourself? https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm-gcc-4.2/trunk/libjava/classpath/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.java To look at the source code for subclasses (and thus implementations of start, etc) google: `<package> <name_of_class> filetype:java`

Answer (score 1):

For simplification of Ryan's answer:
`isRunning()` simply checks if the line is "online" or "running", or basically being active

`isActive()` checks if the line is actively writing or reading information, either inputting or outputting

Dateline JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html

isActive JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#isActive%28%29

isRunning() JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#isRunning%28%29

Comment: Sorry but I can read manuals. I am implementing my own `DataLine` and can't figure out, how to fulfill the contract. Of course I can choose arbitrary states of line from my own. Can you explain by example. Suppose I have microphone line. My program opens it, starts it, then reads from it. At which moment these state transitions will occur?

Comment: See my new update showing an output form the sample with microphone.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not on a computer with a JDK at the moment, I will take a look at those later, when I have time

Comment: The fact is that both flags are changing simultaneously.